# Changing scripts folder in MVC application and using Telerik MVC Extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

I am using the Telerik MVC Extensions and have moved my Scripts folder in to the Content folder. So instead of ...

```
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

... I now have ...

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I realise that I can turn off jQuery inclusion with the `ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false)` method, but how to I tell the Telerik MVC Extensions where the new "base" folder is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set a *base* folder **through the API**, you either follow the MVC convention or you insert your scripts manually. You can, of course, edit the code of the extensions and modify the places where the `ScriptRegistrar` looks for them, in the [`WebAssetDefaultSettings` class](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/allmembers_t_telerik_web_mvc_webassetdefaultsettings.html).

That said, do you really need the scripts in the Content folder?

Comment: Nice one, thanks. I actually added "WebAssetDefaultSettings.ScriptFilesPath = "~/Content/Scripts"; to my Global.asax.cs Application_Start() method. In answer to your question, yes I do, as it's company policy.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what version of the Telerik MVC extensions it came with, but you can call [DefaultPath()](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/web-assets-working-with-javascript-web-assets.html#ChangeDefaultPath) on the default group to change the base directory:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
        .DefaultGroup(g => g.DefaultPath("~/Content/Scripts")
        .Add("Main.js"))
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code formatting is, well not there in the comments, here is my code ...

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication, IContainerAccessor
{

    ...

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        WebAssetDefaultSettings.ScriptFilesPath = "~/Content/Scripts";
    }


    ...
}
```